# plot the centroid values over the existing plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, scipy

How to plot the centroid values as computed below over the plot?

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans, vq

data = np.array(np.random.rand(100))

plt.plot(data, 'ob')


centroids, variances= kmeans(data,3,10)
indices, distances= vq(data,centroids)

print (centroids)
[ 0.82847854  0.49085422  0.18256191]

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot using horizontal lines representing the centroids:

```
plt.plot([0, len(data)], [centroids[0]]*2, lw=1.)
plt.plot([0, len(data)], [centroids[1]]*2, lw=1.)
plt.plot([0, len(data)], [centroids[2]]*2, lw=1.)
```

---

EDIT: or as suggested by @nordev:

```
plt.hlines(centroids, xmin=0, xmax=len(data), lw=1.)
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use the more intuitive [`plt.hlines()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=hlines#matplotlib.pyplot.hlines).